# Is $BA$ a symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transpose

$A,B$ are both n-by-n matrices, and $A^TB=B^TA$.
I know how to prove that $B^TA$ is symmetric, but I don't know how to prove that $BA$ is symmetric (or not).

Comment: Consider the special case of B=A.

Comment: So $BA=B^2$, and I need to prove that $B^2$ is symmetric?

Comment: As you said yourself, or not...

Comment: @eontorch What Steve means is that if you take $B=A$, then $B^TA=A^TA$ is always symmetric. But in this case $BA=A^2$ and $A^2$ is not symmetric in general. It is easy to find such an $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample: Let
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 6 & 0 \\ 0 & 3\end{bmatrix},\;B=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 2 & 0\end{bmatrix},
$$
then
$$
A^T B = \begin{bmatrix} 6 & 0 \\ 0 & 3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 2 & 0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 6 \\ 6 & 0\end{bmatrix}=(A^T B)^T = B^T A,
$$
but
$$
BA=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 2 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 6 & 0 \\ 0 & 3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0& 3\\ 12 & 0\end{bmatrix}\ne (BA)^T.
$$